# Resources Not Found Exception

Tags: java, android

I have a variable int nextvalue. This is set via

```
nextvalue = b.getInt(b.getColumnIndex("nextq"));
```

It is definitely being set correctly as a following query relies on this value. The problem is occurring when I am trying something like

```
text.setText(nextvalue);
```

Am I going crazy is there something simple im missing?

Comment: What's the specific error you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `text.setText(Integer.toString(nextvalue));`

Answer to the same situation [here](http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/resources-notfoundexception/).
In short it says:

> To set the text of a view
> using an integer, you need to do:
>
> view.setText(Integer.toString(iSomeInteger))
>
> The problem is that setText(int) is
> reserved for string resource ids.